# Save user in database, Spring Security Registration form

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am studying Spring Security.
Cant save registrated user(if he is registring at least, cause i cant know)

WebSecurityConfig:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/registration").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService)
                .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
    }
```

User Entity:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    Set<Role> roles;
    ...constructors
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return getRoles();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```java
    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String registration(){

        return "registration";
    }
    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String addUser(User user, Map<String, Object> model) {
        User userFromDb = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
        if (userFromDb != null) {
            model.put("message", "User exists!");
            return "registration";
        }
        user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(Role.USER));
        userRepository.save(user);

        return "redirect:/login";
```

Thymeleaf:
hello:

```html
<form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
</form>
```

login:

```html
<div th:if="${param.error}">
    Invalid username and password.
</div>
<div th:if="${param.logout}">
    You have been logged out.
</div>
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
    <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
    <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
</form>
```

registration:

```html
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <div><label>User Name: <input type="text" name="username"></label></div>
    <div><label>Password: <input type="text" name="username"></label></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Sign in"></div>
</form>
<a href="/registration">Add new User</a>
```

I dont know where i have to fix(in frontend in forms or in backend)
What is going on exactly with my registration form and how can i add "saving of users"?

And if possible, I would like to know, what the diffrence betweet thymeleaf/freemaker/mustache and which one i have to use?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Register Mapping
@RequestMapping(value = "/registerUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerPage(Registration reg,HttpSession session) {
      RegisterUser exitingUser = service.findUserByEmail(reg.getEmail());
      if (exitingUser == null) {
          RegisterUser user = new RegisterUser ();
          user.setEmail(reg.getEmail());
          user.setPass(reg.getPass());
          service.registerNewUserAccount(user); 

      }
    }

// User Model
public class User extends BasicEntity {

        /** */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @ValidEmail
        @Column(name = "EMAIL_ID", nullable = false)
        private String email_id;

        @Column(name = "PASSWORD", length = 60, nullable = false)
        private String password;

        @Column(name = "ENABLED")
        private boolean enabled;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
        private Set<Privilege> privileges;

        @Transient
        private String matchingPassword;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
        @JoinTable(name = "USER_DETAILS_ROLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
        private Set<Role> roles;


        public RegistrationDetails() {
            super();
            this.enabled = false;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getPass() {
            return pass;
        }

        public void setPass(String pass) {
            this.pass = pass;
        }

        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return enabled;
        }

        public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
            this.enabled = enabled;
        }

        public String getMatchingPassword() {
            return matchingPassword;
        }

        public void setMatchingPassword(String matchingPassword) {
            this.matchingPassword = matchingPassword;
        }

        @JsonIgnore
        public Set<Role> getRoles() {
            return roles;
        }

        public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
            this.roles = roles;
        }



        @JsonIgnore
        public Set<Privilege> getPermissions() {
            return privileges;
        }

        public void setPermissions(Set<Privilege> privileges) {
            this.privileges= privileges;
        }

        public static long getSerialversionuid() {
            return serialVersionUID;
        }

        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Collection<Role> roles) {
            List<String> userRole = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Role role : roles) {
                userRole.add(role.getName());
            }
            return getGrantedAuthorities(userRole);
        }

        private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> privileges) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String privilege : privileges) {
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(privilege));
            }
            return authorities;
        }


//security config

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/resources/**", "/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/").permitAll().usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check").failureUrl("/")
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler()).and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .logoutUrl("/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").and().csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new AuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }



    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }
```

//Hope this will Help you

Comment: thanks much, will try to understand what is happening here.